# xpath php, grabbing elements inside certain tags/comment

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using PHPDomDocument.

I have this HTML

```
regular html page... 
<!-- TAG -->
SOME HTML ... .
 <div...
<script...
etc..
<!-- END TAG -->
closing regular html page
```

I'd like to loop all the HTML elements inside TAG / ENDTAG.

Any ideas without Regex?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: only with regex, and it works, but I would like to avoid that.